# Get LatLng from Zip Code - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

All I want is some simple example code that shows me how to obtain a latlng element from an inputted zip code OR a city/state.

Comment: Is there a specific language your looking for your example to be in?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Couldn't you just call the following replaceing the {zipcode} with the zip code or city and state
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={zipcode}

[Google Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Here is a link with a How To Geocode using JavaScript: [Geocode walk-thru](http://www.wikihow.com/Geocode-an-Address-in-Google-Maps-Javascript). If you need the specific lat/lng numbers call geometry.location.lat() or geometry.location.lng() ([API for google.maps.LatLng class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng))

EXAMPLE to get lat/lng:

```
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = {zipcode} or {city and state};
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
         lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    alert('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Logitude: ' + lng);
```

Comment: This is not wrong but sometimes doesn't get some places even when google maps site does, the way that worked for me is: instead of this { 'address': zipcode} I replaced like this { 'address': 'zipcode  '+zipcode  }, i just added the string 'zipcode ' before the zipcode and it works better.

Answer (score 21):

Just a hint: **zip codes are not worldwide unique** so this is worth to provide country ISO code in the request (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

e.g looking for coordinates of polish (iso code `PL`) zipcode `01-210`:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=01210,PL`

how to obtain user country code?

if you would like to get your user country info based on IP address there are services for it, e.g you can do GET request on:
http://ip-api.com/json

Comment: thanks for the hint, just using address=01210 did not deliver a correct result. with the ",PL" addition it works fine!

Answer (score 8):

Here is the most reliable way to get the lat/long from zip code (i.e. postal code):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&components=postal_code:97403
```

Comment: API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.

Answer (score 5):

This is just an improvement to the previous answers because it didn't work for me with some zipcodes even when in https://www.google.com/maps it does, I fixed just adding the word "zipcode " before to put the zipcode, like this:

```js
function getLatLngByZipcode(zipcode) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = zipcode;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'zipcode '+address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
    return [latitude, longitude];
}
```

Comment: This was a big help for numbers like 12345 which give street address results by default. Thanks. In combination with a country-code suffix (,US) it does an even better job of assuming that an address is being provided, and not a business name. Good stuff, as long as you're searching only one country.

Comment: doesn't work in return it will be showing undefined

Answer (score 5):

While working on my internship project I found a website for this https://thezipcodes.com/
Create a free account and get the API key from account Section.

```js
https://thezipcodes.com/api/v1/search?zipCode={zipCode}&countryCode={2digitCountryCode}&apiKey={apiKey}
```

I found majority of data here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function I am using for my work

```
function getLatLngByZipcode(zipcode) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = zipcode;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
    return [latitude, longitude];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
<script>
    var latitude = '';
    var longitude = '';

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode(
    { 
       componentRestrictions: { 
           country: 'IN', 
           postalCode: '744102'
       } 
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            console.log(latitude + ", " + longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to extract the Lat / Lng from a zip code using a Python package!

```
import pgeocode

nomi = pgeocode.Nominatim('us')
query = nomi.query_postal_code("90001")

data = {
    "lat": query["latitude"],
    "lon": query["longitude"]
}

print(data)
```