# Javascript function returns undefined instead of a number

Tags: javascript

I have two Javascript functions that try to find the latitude and longitude of an address using Google Maps API Geocode:

```
function getLatLon(address) {
    var location = -1;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            location = new Array(lat, lon);
            //document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = location[0];
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful.");
        }
    });
    return location;
}

function search() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var location = getLatLon(address);
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = location[0];
}
```

While the location[0] inside getLatLon() prints out the correct number in the #results div, the location[0] inside search() returns undefined. Do you have any ideas why this might happen? I've tried returning a plain string ("Hello") from getLatLon() instead and that works just fine.

Comment: Is `geocoder.geocode` asynchronous? If yes, `getLatLon` should always return -1. *Always*

Comment: **Uh**, I have a question. How can `getLatLon` returning `undefined`? `location` is `-1`, so it should be returning `-1` as well.

Comment: @Derek - I think the problem is `location[0]` is undefined not `getLatLon()`. Poor question wording IMO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to return Geocode latLng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694944/not-able-to-return-geocode-latlng)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `geocoder.geocode(...)` is **asynchronous** so you can't return a value. Try it like this instead:

```
function getLatLon(address, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            location = new Array(lat, lon);
            callback(location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful.");
        }
    });
}

function search() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    getLatLon(address, function(location) {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = location[0];
    });
}
```

Comment: Clearly I need a better understanding of callbacks. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who has a similar problem, here's an [article](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) I used to understand callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder), calling `geocoder.geocode(request, callback_function)` will return nothing right away. When the response has been received and processed, the `callback_function` will be called. Until then, `location` will be left at whatever value you set it.

You need to start the search itself in the call-back function when you call `getLatLon`. For flexibility, you might do this by adding a call-back parameter to `getLatLon` that will be called from within the `geocode()` call-back function.