# Enter string into search field with Scrapy Spider; loading the generated URL

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, search-box

Would the correct method with a Scrapy Spider for entering a zip code value "27517" automatically within the entry box on this website: [Locations of Junkyards](http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/) be to use a Form Request?
Here is what I have right now:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class LkqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "lkq" 
allowed_domains = ["http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/"]
start_urls = ['http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/']

def start_requests(self):
return [ FormRequest("http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/",
             formdata={'dnnVariable':'27517'},
             callback=self.parse) ]

def parsel(self):
print self.status
```

It doesn't do anything when run though, is Form Request mainly for completing login fields? What would be the best way to get to [THIS](http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/tag/All/m/24902/fullcrit/27517?lat=35.8263369&lng=-79.0419053) page? (which comes up after the search for the zip 27517 and is where I would start scraping my desired information with a scrapy spider)

Comment: For a start you will probably need to populate all the form fields including the hidden ones not just __dnnVariable. So you will have to parse out variavbles for __VIEWSTATE etc. which are hidden fields. Then it looks like it is using a lot of JavaScript so you will have to deal with somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't really a FormRequest as FormRequests is only a name for a POST request in scrapy, and of course it helps you fill a form, but a form is also normally a POST request.

You need some debugging console (I prefer Firebug for Firefox) to check which requests are being done, and it looks like it is a GET request and quite simple to replicate, the url would be something like [this](http://www.lkqcorp.com/en-us/locationResults/tag/All/m/24902/fullcrit/27517?lat=35.8263369&lng=-79.0419053) where you'll have to change the number after `/fullcrit/` to the desired zip code, but you also need the `lat` and `lng` arguments, for that you could use the Google Maps API, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586056/858913) for an example on how to get it, but to summarise just do [this Request](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=27517) and get the `location` argument.